# java Script redirect to another url doesn't work, it appends the url

Tags: javascript

I want to scan an QR Code with an url, and when it scans it should redirect to the url page from the QR Code, but it only appends it to my current URL, so it redirects to an false URL

```
var scanner = new Instascan.Scanner({ video: document.getElementById('preview'), scanPeriod: 5, mirror: false });
        scanner.addListener('scan',function(content){
            //alert(content);
            console.log("Das ist der Content: " + content);
            //window.location.href='content';
            window.location = content;
        });
```

it should redirect to 'http://digital-selforder.com/suche.php?zid=1ABCDE'
but it could be any url or something like google.com

Comment: Can you also post the result of the QR scanning?

Comment: I meant what it **actually** generates, not what it _should_ generate.

Comment: oh sorry, the url is https://myipadress/selforder/digital-selforder.com/suche.php?zid=1ABCDE so it seems to me that it just appends it to my current url

Answer (score 0):

i just needed to add http:// to my url, otherwise it couldn't redirect, so now it takes me to the right website

```
var scanner = new Instascan.Scanner({video: document.getElementById('preview'), scanPeriod: 5, mirror: false});
        scanner.addListener('scan', function (content) {
            //alert(content);
            console.log("Das ist der Content: " + content);
            window.location.replace("http://" + content);

        });
```

Comment: That makes sense. If a URL does not contain a protocol or machine information, clients are instructed to interpret the URL as relative, thus appending the Content to the current URL is expected behavior. Refer to RFC 1808 for more information: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1808